# Generate sum of all possible combinations of id

Tags: tuples, combinations, stata

I have a dataset with the structure that looks something like this:

```
    Group ID Value
    1 A 10
    1 B 15
    1 C 20
    2 D 10
    2 E 25
```

Within each Group, I want to obtain the sum of all possible combinations of two or more IDs. For instance, within group 1, I can have the following combinations: AB, AC, BC, ABC. So, in total I have four possible combinations for group 1, of which I'd like to get the sum of the variable value.
I am using the formula for combinations of N elements in groups of size R to identify how many observations I need to add to the dataset to have enough observations.
For Group 1, the number of observations I need are:

3!/((3-2)!*2!)*2 = 6 for the two-IDs combinations
3!/(3-3)!*3!)*3 = 3 for the three-IDs combination.

So a total of 9 observations. Since I already have three, I can use the command:`expand 6 if Group==1`. For Group 1 I would get something like

```
    Group ID Value
    1 A 10
    1 B 15
    1 C 20
    1 A 10
    1 B 15
    1 C 20
    1 A 10
    1 B 15
    1 C 20
```

Now, I am stuck here on how to proceed to tell Stata to identify the combinations and create the summation. Ideally, I want to create two new variables, to identify the tuples and get the summation, so something that looks like:

```
    Group ID Value Touple Sum
    1 A 10 AB 25
    1 B 15 AB 25
    1 A 10 AC 30
    1 C 20 AC 30
    1 B 15 BC 35
    1 C 20 BC 35
    1 A 10 ABC 45
    1 B 15 ABC 45
    1 C 20 ABC 45
```

In this way, I could then just drop the duplicates in terms of Group and Tuples. Once I have the Tuples variable, getting the sum is straightforward, but getting the Tuples, I can't get my head around it.
Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried doing this with nested loops and the `tuples` command.

First I create and save a tempfile to store results:

```
clear 
tempfile group_results 
save `group_results', replace emptyok
```

Then I input and save data, along with a local for the number of groups:

```
clear 
input Group str1 ID Value
    1 A 10
    1 B 15
    1 C 20
    2 D 10
    2 E 25 
    2 F 13    // added to test
    2 G 2     // added to test
end 

sum Group 
local num_groups = r(max)

tempfile base 
save `base', replace
```

Here's the core of the code. The outer loop here iterates over Groups. Then it makes a list of the IDs in that group, and uses the `tuples` command to make a list of the unique combinations of those IDs, with a minimum size of 2. The k loop iterates through the number of tuples and the m loop makes an indicator for tuple membership. Note that this uses two community-contributed commands: [`tuples`](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s456797.html) and `gegen` from the [gtools package](https://gtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), both available via SSC.

```
forvalues i = 1/`num_groups' {
    display "Starting Group `i'"
    use `base' if Group==`i', clear 
    * Make list of IDs to get unique combos of 
    forvalues j = 1/`=_N' {
        local tuple_list`i' = "`tuple_list`i'' " + ID[`j']
    }
    * Get all unique combos in list using tuples command
    tuples `tuple_list`i'', display min(2)
    forvalues k = 1/`ntuples' {
        display "Tuple `k':  `tuple`k''"
        local length = wordcount("`tuple`k''")
        gen intuple=0
        gen tuple`k'="`tuple`k''"
        forvalues m = 1/`length' {
            replace intuple=1 if ID==word("`tuple`k''",`m')
        }
        * Calculate sum of values in that tuple
        gegen group_sum`k' = sum(Value) if intuple==1 
        drop intuple 
        list 
    }
    * Reshape into desired format
    reshape long tuple group_sum, i(Group ID Value) j(tuple_num)
    drop if missing(group_sum)
    sort tuple_num 
    list 
    append using `group_results'
    save `group_results', replace 
}

* Full results
use `group_results', clear 
sort Group tuple_num
list
```

I hope this helps. The `list` commands will give you a busy results window but it shows what's all happening. Here's the output at the end of the i loop for Group 1:

```
     +--------------------------------------------------+
     | Group   ID   Value   tuple_~m   tuple   group_~m |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. |     1    C      20          1     B C         35 |
  2. |     1    B      15          1     B C         35 |
  3. |     1    A      10          2     A C         30 |
  4. |     1    C      20          2     A C         30 |
  5. |     1    A      10          3     A B         25 |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  6. |     1    B      15          3     A B         25 |
  7. |     1    C      20          4   A B C         45 |
  8. |     1    A      10          4   A B C         45 |
  9. |     1    B      15          4   A B C         45 |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

This could be inefficient if your data is actually much larger!

Comment: I can see why this could be inefficient in a large dataset (and, indeed, my real dataset has tens of thousands of observations), but it is still more efficient than not doing it! 

It is a brilliang use of the tuples command, very much appreciated!

Comment: Good work! (Bounty on its way.) Need to document that `gegen` and `tuples` are community-contributed.